# Best way to manage custom expressions in scala

Tags: scala, null, operators, overloading, abstract-syntax-tree

I am creating a new Abstract Syntax Tree for custom untyped expressions, and I wanted to redefine the == operator on it, like that:

```
trait Expression {
  def ==(other: Expression): Expression = Equality(this, other)
  def !=(other: Expression): Expression = Inequality(this, other)
}
case class Equality(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
case class Inequality(e1: Expression, e2: Expression) extends Expression
case class Integer(e: Int) extends Expression
case class Boolean(e: Boolean) extends Expression
```

The only problem I now encounter is to test the nullity of such expression.
For example, when I write this :

```
val formula: Expression = someFunctionReturingAnExpression
if(formula != null) {
  ... use the formula.
}
```

it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, because it is applying the method `!=` to `formula`.

Any good idea on how to have the expressibility of `!=` and also the null check ?

Comment: I think you should look for another symbol for your DSL (in)equality, like `~`,`!~`.

Comment: Side note: don't use null if you can help it. If there's a value of type `T` that might be null, use `Option[T]` instead.

Comment: An addition to the side note above: make your base trait extend `NotNull` to get even more guarantees, that it won't be used incorrectly by someone else: `trait Expression extends NotNull`. Now if you try to `val formula: Expression = null`, you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overloading the `==`, `!=` operators there. The code you showed doesn't really compile for me since it cannot cast Expression to Boolean in the if clause. So you could use a downcast on the null there so that the compiler uses the `==` operator from `Any`:

```
if (formula != null.asInstanceOf[Any]) {
    println("hello")
}
```

The above expression works for me.

You can also use the reference equality operator from `AnyRef`:

```
if (formula eq null) {
    println("hello")
}

if (formula ne null) {
    println("!hello")
}
```

I also subscribe to ziggystar and Dylan's comments - you should use a different operator name (`===`, for example) and don't use `null` - use `Option` instead.